# Program to turn a list with certain attributes into a table format

Tags: list, excel, sorting, vba

I have a text document that has several hundred items listed with specific attributes. Here is an example, where the items are fruits followed by attributes:

```
Fruit: Banana
Shape: Long
Color: Yellow
Texture: Smooth
Seeds: No

Fruit: Orange
Color: Orange
Shape: Round

Fruit: Strawberry
Color: Red
Seeds: Yes
```

etc....

I would like to turn this into a table format (would like to import it into Excel), as shown in this example I made in Excel:

[image: http://imgur.com/5KxthKz]

Things to notice are that there are only a few types of attributes (5 in the example, 12 in my actual list). However, notice that not every item has every attribute listed, and the attributes are sometimes listed in differing orders (I tried to make this obvious in my fruit example. Not all the fruit have a "Shape" listed, and the "Shape" may come before "Color" or after "Color").

If someone who is more knowledgable than me can think of an Excel macro that would be ideal, but I am willing to try other methods.

Comment: Read the list into a string (or if you prefer copy/paste to a sheet in Excel) Loop through the lines/cells and split on ":". If the first part is "Fruit" then start a new line in your table, else find the required attribute column and place the value there.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm too much of a novice to know how to do that. I need someone willing to actually write the macro for me and I know enough that I could modify it for my actual dataset. But thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple Java program to do the following:

1. read every line. When there is a Fruit, store the fruit name it into a stringBuffer, use ", " (comma + space) to separate the attributes. So your string will be like: "Banana, Long, Yellow, Smooth, NO".
2. Put all kinds of fruits into a string vector.
3. Write your strings into a text file.
4. Now your fruits are separate by ", ". Use NotePad++ to open this text file, and replace ", " with tab-space.
5. Excel cells are separated by 'Tab-space'. Therefore, after replacing all the ", ", you can directly copy your text into Excel. That fills all the cells at once!!!!

I wrote a article about turning list into table on my site, if you are interested.  http://www.shawnfandev.com/wordpress/2014/07/23/turn-list-into-excel-sheet/